# ASP.NET master page meta:resourcekey

Tags: asp.net, localization, master-pages

I know we can use localization pattern in ASP.NET pages which makes possible to have multi-language web application. I tried same technique for Master page but it does not work. I have master page and 2 main.master.resx and main.master.de.resx page, then I wan have value from these pages for text of lable . It works in aspx pages, but not for master pages. Any idea or help please?

code:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" meta:resourcekey="string1"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check that:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34100/Master-Page-Globalization

Comment: that doesn't answer the question, that just shows how to add a language selector to the master page, not how to create resx files for a master page